# Android AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Ok, I've tried two examples of AlarmManager- one from the commonsware website, and one from the manning website.
The code I am currently working with is from the manning website : [http://unlocking-android.googlecode.com/svn/chapter8/trunk/SimpleAlarm/][1]

There are two classes, AlarmReceiver and GenerateAlarm. Anyone have any idea why the toast will not display in the emulator? I was thinking that it was because I am located in the Eastern Time Zone and it uses UTC, but I have fiddled with different things and none of them seem to work.

```
public class GenerateAlarm extends Activity {

Toast mToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_alarm_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this.mOneShotListener);
}

private OnClickListener mOneShotListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(GenerateAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(GenerateAlarm.this, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
       // calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), appIntent);

        if (GenerateAlarm.this.mToast != null) {
            GenerateAlarm.this.mToast.cancel();
        }
        GenerateAlarm.this.mToast = Toast.makeText(GenerateAlarm.this, R.string.alarm_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //GenerateAlarm.this.mToast.show();
    }
};

}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceiveIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your toast in the `onReceived` method where you should add the handling of the intent received.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

`onReceiveIntent` is not a method of [broadcastreceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

> public abstract void onReceive
>   (Context context, Intent intent)
>
> Since: API Level 1 This method is
>   called when the BroadcastReceiver is
>   receiving an Intent broadcast.

Comment: I just figured this out, and was coming back to report that I had figured it out when I saw this answer.... haha, thank you!